# Make: run common pre/post rules for a set of targets

Tags: graph, makefile, dependencies

I want to build the following dependency graph, but with `pre` and `post` being artifact free:

[image: make dependency graph]

Before creating/updating any of `a`, `b`, or `c` the command `pre` should run once and afterwards `post` should run once. Both do not and preferably should not produce artifacts. And of course, these should **only** be run if any of `a b c` have **changed**. This should all be triggered by a phony `all` target, i.e. `a` is never run independently.

Using order-only prerequisites `a: | pre` does not help because these are *always* run. Making `post` depend on `a b c` won't work because then it is also run all the time because `post` does not create an artifact.

If this is impossible and artifacts are required after all, how would `pre` (the more interesting of the two) only run if any of the targets which depend on it have changed?

*Note:* `a` etc. are normal makefile targets (which could be called independently), e.g.:

```
a: a.in a.dependency
    @echo Creating a
    @mkabc a.in > a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one way in make to force a command to execute before target X is built, but only if target X needs to be built, and that's put the command as the first thing in the recipe for target X.  There's no way to manipulate the dependency graph in GNU make so that make determines if a target needs to be built and, if so, first builds some other target before the recipe runs.

So you will definitely have to use recursive make here, putting the command to build the `pre` target into the recipe of the other targets.  However, of course that will cause it to be built multiple times which you don't want.

One way to get around that is to play a trick using `eval`.  Try this (untested):

```
BUILD_PRE = $(shell $(MAKE) -j1 pre >/dev/null)

post: a b c
        echo $@

pre:
        echo $@

a b c:
        $(BUILD_PRE)$(eval BUILD_PRE =)
        touch $@

.PHONY: pre post
```

In the rule for `a`, `b`, and `c` we first expand the `BUILD_PRE` variable which results in a recursive make invocation via the `shell` call.  Then the `eval` expansion will reset the value of `BUILD_PRE` so that it's now empty; this means in subsequent rules for `b` and `c` this first line will expand to the empty string and `pre` will not be run again.

You may ask, why do we need to use `shell` here?  Can't we just use:

```
BUILD_PRE = $(MAKE) -j1 pre
```

so that the first recipe contained a recursive make?  The problem with this is that it won't work with parallel make.  Suppose the first target make attempts to build is `a` (it will always be of course).  That recipe will contain a recursive make invocation and make will start it.  But if you are using `-j` make does not wait for that recipe to complete: it will go try to start `b` and `c`.  Since `BUILD_PRE` is now empty you only get one build of `pre`, but `b` and `c` are not waiting for `pre` to be completed.

By using a `shell` function the recursive invocation is forced to complete when the recipe is expanded, before any other recipe is started.

I should say, I suspect there may be a few odd things about this.  In particular when make *normally* invokes a recursive build it does some setup etc. that won't happen when a recursive build is invoked through `shell`.  But, it should work.

**Edit:** Final Makefile with '+' prefix to mark recursive make calls:

```
all: allabc

BUILD_PRE = $(shell $(MAKE) pre)
BUILD_POST =

pre:
    @echo PRE abc >&2

post:
    @echo POST abc >&2

allabc: a b c
    @+$(BUILD_POST) > /dev/null

a:
    +$(BUILD_PRE)$(eval BUILD_PRE = )
    touch "$@"
    $(eval BUILD_POST = $$(MAKE) post)
b:
    +$(BUILD_PRE)$(eval BUILD_PRE = )
    touch "$@"
    $(eval BUILD_POST = $$(MAKE) post)
c:
    +$(BUILD_PRE)$(eval BUILD_PRE = )
    touch "$@"
    $(eval BUILD_POST = $$(MAKE) post)

clean:
    rm -f a b c
```

Comment: Wonderful trick (as usual). May I suggest `echo $@ >&2` in `pre` recipe, instead of just `echo $@`? This way it should be visible. With the current version it is sent to the standard output which is redirected to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Good point.  Another thought is to use `BUILD_PRE = $(info $(shell $(MAKE) -j1 pre))` which would print the output of the recursive make.

Comment: That is great indeed. And while setting up the same hack for BUILD_POST I came across the error `warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.`, and then (after removing `-j1`) `warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.`  **Add '+'?** - that is hard to search for so I got the entire make manual as text file and section 7.3 (also 5.7.1) mentions "The '+' prefix marks those recipe lines as "recursive"": So the BUILD_POST rule is `BUILD_POST =`, `allabc: a b c  \n  @+$(BUILD_POST) > /dev/null` and `$(eval BUILD_POST = $$(MAKE)  post)` in `a b c etc`.

Comment: @finitegraygreen: You could even factorize a bit more by putting `$(eval BUILD_POST = $$(MAKE) post)` at the end of the `BUILD_PRE` definition, instead of adding it to all your `a`, `b`, `c`... recipes.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - Indeed: `BUILD_PRE = $(shell $(MAKE) pre) $(eval BUILD_POST = $(MAKE) post)`. I wonder if `+$(BUILD_PRE)$(eval BUILD_PRE = )` can be further shortened to something like `$(eval ABC_GROUP)` or if that is as far as indirections can go.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand all the details but assuming you want to build your 5 targets when invoking `make all`, with the dependencies you show (and maybe `a`, `b` and `c` in parallel), you can, for instance:

```
.PHONY: all pre post

all:
    $(MAKE) pre
    $(MAKE) a b c
    $(MAKE) post

pre:
    <pre-recipe>

post:
    <post-recipe>

a:
    <a-recipe>
...
```

Comment: Ah, recursive make! But even with this trick `pre` and `post` are always run, even if `a`, `b`, and `c` are up to date.

Comment: Well, I probably misunderstood what you mean by "_`a`, `b` and `c` are up to date_". In your dependency graph they depend only on phony target `pre`, so my assumption was that you want them rebuilt every time you invoke `make all`. If it is not what you want you should probably explain how to decide if `a`, `b` and `c` must be rebuilt or not.

Comment: These are "standard" rules, e.g. `a: a.in  \n\t cp a.in a` etc. I'll update the question.